# Chaining two tasks

Tags: gradle

In gradle 1.7, how to go about ensuring a task will always run when another one has run

```groovy
task after_eclipse << {
   println 'After eclipse'
}
```

I've failed with

```groovy
after_eclipse.dependsOn eclipse
after_eclipse.mustRunAfter eclipse
```

And I can't use shouldRunAfter because it appeared only in [1.10](http://www.gradle.org/docs/1.10/release-notes#shouldrunafter-task-ordering)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `after_eclipse.dependsOn eclipse`, `after_eclipse` will run after `eclipse` if and only if it's *invoked* (added to task queue). Similar rules applies to `mustRunAfter`. [Here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:ordering_tasks) you can find rules regarding to task ordering.

Why don't You add a task action to `eclipse` task?

```
tasks.eclipse << {
   //after eclipse
}
```

Comment: Because eclipse task is the one in `org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse`

Comment: With `eclipse <<` I've got the error:  `Could not find method leftShift() for arguments [...] on org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseModel_Decorated`